# How to get observable object value?

Tags: java, observable

In the observer class in java, how can I refer to the Observable objects values, such as its name, from the update method?

say I have this update method in the observer class:

```
public void update(Observable o, Object arg){

    System.out.println(o.name); // I want to get object o's name value but I don't know how
```

any help? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can typecast `o` with desired class. Same can be done as below.

```
if(o instanceof  YOUR_CLASS_NAME){}

    System.out.println(((YOUR_CLASS_NAME)o).name);
```

Comment: is there anyway of doing this with private fields? the name value was private but your solution only works if I make name public.

Comment: Yes, and as adviced Always make use of getter and setter function to access property instead of direct access.  In  your case if name field is private. Try doing this,  System.out.println(((YOUR_CLASS_NAME)o).getName());

Comment: A safer alternative would be to create an `Interface` which contains the methods you need, that all your observable objects implement. That way you don't need the `if` statement; you can simply cast to the interface type.